# The link doesn't work if I change its position in the code

Tags: jquery, html, css

Something weird is happening and I can't figure out what the problem might be.

```js
var imageSliding = $('.box > .img');

//Lighbox & back shadow

$('.lightbox').click(function() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '.50'
  }, 300, 'linear');
  $('.box').animate({
    'opacity': '1.00'
  }, 300, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  close_box();
});

$('.backdrop').click(function() {
  close_box();
});

function close_box() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 300, 'linear', function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
  });
}

/* Slider */
var speed = 100;

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":visible"),
    last = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(":last"),
    prev = now.prev();
  prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    prev.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(':visible'),
    first = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery").children(':first'),
    next = now.next();
  next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    next.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});

$(".gallery li").click(function() {
  var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
    next = $(this).next();
  next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
  $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
    next.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  width: 40%;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .box {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .box {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
  .box {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.prev:active,
.next:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.gallery li {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.gallery li:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.gallery img {
  max-height: 550px;
}

.slideButtons {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Welcome Within</h1>
  <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <ul class="gallery" id="olympGallery">
      <li><img src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/trabzoni/trabzoni1.png" alt="" title="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/trabzoni/trabzoni2.png" alt="" title="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/trabzoni/trabzoni3.png" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="slideButtons">
      <span class="next">Next</span>
      <span class="prev">Previous</span>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>This thing is called 'Caption'. Let me tell you:</p>
      <hr />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you see this class "sliderButtons"?
yes, when it's on the bottom of the ul it doesn't work, and whn I put it on the top of the ul, it works..kinda weird for me.

I want the buttons to be on the bottom though, I tried changing the span to `<a>` or `<button>` but not use.

Comment: this is because when button are up then `var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.gallery")` is correctly formed but when it's on bottom `next("ul.gallery")` is not worked. then use `prev("ul.gallery")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) which target immediately **following** sibling thus it works when you place `slideButtons` before `UL` element

You should use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `.box` then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)to target the desired element;

```
var gallery = $(this).closest('.box').find("ul.gallery"),
    now = gallery.children(":visible"),
    last = gallery.children(":last"),
```

```js
var imageSliding = $('.box > .img');
$('.lightbox').click(function() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '.50'
  }, 300, 'linear');
  $('.box').animate({
    'opacity': '1.00'
  }, 300, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  close_box();
});

$('.backdrop').click(function() {
  close_box();
});

function close_box() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 300, 'linear', function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
  });
}

/* Slider */
var speed = 100;

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var gallery = $(this).closest('.box').find("ul.gallery"),
    now = gallery.children(":visible"),
    last = gallery.children(":last"),
    prev = now.prev();
  prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    prev.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  var gallery = $(this).closest('.box').find("ul.gallery"),
    now = gallery.children(":visible"),
    last = gallery.children(":last"),
    next = now.next();
  next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    next.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});

$(".gallery li").click(function() {
  var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
    next = $(this).next();
  next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
  $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
    next.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  background: white;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  width: 40%;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .box {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .box {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
  .box {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.prev:active,
.next:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.gallery li {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.gallery li:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.gallery img {
  max-height: 550px;
}

.slideButtons {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Welcome Within</h1>
  <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <ul class="gallery" id="olympGallery">
      <li><img src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/trabzoni/trabzoni1.png" alt="" title="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/trabzoni/trabzoni2.png" alt="" title="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/trabzoni/trabzoni3.png" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="slideButtons">
      <span class="next">Next</span>
      <span class="prev">Previous</span>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>This thing is called 'Caption'. Let me tell you:</p>
      <hr />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okaaaay!! Thank you for this info, I should read about that .closest()